# Regex - how to negate a group of substring in a string

Tags: regex

I want to create a numeric pattern of 4 digits such that there is at least one non-zero number.
So, it can be "1234", "0001" but not "0000". Also, we must not use the lookahead operator and the lookbehind operator.

my current pattern `[0-9]{4}`. I can't seem to understand how to remove just "0000".

Comment: I think you've excluded your only solution: regexes in general can't specify negatives, you need lookahead / lookbehind for that. It might be useful to specify _why_ you can't use those - are you using a language that doesn't have them, but which might have some other advanced feature you could use?

Comment: You could try regex `^0{0,3}[1-9][0-9]{0,3}` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/l2cQna/2

Comment: @ThanLUONG That looks like an answer, not a comment to improve the question.

Comment: @IMSoP 
This post has been closed. So, I cannot answer. I have to respond as a comment.

Comment: @ThanLUONG Well, you don't _have to_ respond at all, and the Closed status is suggesting that you don't. If you disagree, you can suggest the post be reopened, but just working around the system by misusing comments isn't that helpful in the long run.

Comment: @IMSoP actually it's a class assignment and that is the requirement from professor. I am not able to solve because I m getting stuck at the negation of "0000" part

Answer (score 1):

It's in fact very easy. You will need to specify the following:

- four digits, from which the first is not 0
- OR
- four digits, from which the second is not 0
- OR
- four digits, from which the third is not 0
- OR
- four digits, from which the fourth is not 0

## Disjunction regex

Use the `|` operator.

## Digit

```
[0-9]
```

## Non-zero digit

```
[1-9]
```

## Summary

In this answer you find everything you need. Since this is homework, I will let you work out the formula. Happy thinking!

Answer (score -2):

As per Lajos's suggestion

```
^[1-9][\d]{3}|^[\d][1-9][\d]{2}|^[\d]{2}[1-9]\d|[\d]{3}[1-9]
```

Comment: I have avoided writing the actual code to let Tade do it. But since your code seems to be correct, I have upvoted it.